# mysql like does not give any results even though there are records in the table

Tags: php, mysql

```
select id
from Table
where title like  '%Dir Clinical - Acting Clinical Director%'
    OR title like  '%Dir Clinical - Assistant Director of Nursing%'
```

mysql like does not give any results for the above query,even though there are records in the table, may be due to hyphen in between. But when i try to remove the text before hyphen and query with the remaining text, getting wrong results

Could any one of you explain this issue, where getting zero results with there is a hyphen in between the text while applying like

Comment: if you remove one or both like statements do you get any results?

Comment: try something simpler, like `like '%Clinical%'. **EVERYTHING** between the `%` has to be an exact match, though it can match anywhere inside the field. e.g. maybe your records don't have a `-` char, they have an ndash or mdash.

Comment: yes, when i remove the like statementi will get all the results

Comment: The hyphens sometimes varies, especially from word you get different types of hyphens, Can you make sure that is not the source

Comment: no this is not from word, i am getting this issue while trying to run a search

Comment: Can you please export a feasibly small chunk of sample data from your database (preferably as valid `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements) and the relevant (simplified?) part of the php script (and before adding it to your question text, test it with this data set and script)? see http://sscce.org/

Comment: You can also use multiple `%` throughout your `like` comparison that might work out for you. As stated before though, not all hyphens are created equally and multiple `%`s might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you have two wilcards, `%` to match multiple characters and `_` to match exactly one character. So assuming the hyphen really is the problem, you can try:

```
 '%Dir Clinical _ Acting Clinical Director%'
```

That will allow any character to be in the hyphen spot, and solve the problem of unicode hyphens vs regular or similar issues.

Comment: no this is not the one,i was asking for, presently i am working with hyphen not underscore, and the query result is zero

Comment: this trick worked for me,but i don't know why hyphen not working in this case.